# Set maximum Actionmailer sending rate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, amazon-ses

Is there an easy way to set a maximum rate for Actionmailer to send out emails? I'm using Amazon SES which drops messages sent at more than 5 per second and i want to avoid hitting that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy solution to this. When you call a `deliver` method, ActionMailer sends the message synchronously: it immediately sends the message, and the caller waits for it to finish sending.

So, since ActionMailer isn't running in the background to process a queue of messages, it can't really keep track of its rate or postpone a delivery.

But! It looks like [Rails 4 will support asynchronous ActionMailer](http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/ruby/2012/06/26/rails-4-sneak-peek-async-actionmailer.html), based on the [resque-mailer](https://github.com/zapnap/resque_mailer) gem which is usable today (with some extra setup). From there, you might be able to look at limiting the rate at which Resque processes the enqueued jobs.